# Error viewing datatable in vs 2013

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013

When i try to view a dataset or datatable in vs2013 i get this error.

```
CustomerExceptionDataHolder cannot be cast to CustomExceptionDataHolder.
```

[image]

I just changed from 2010 to 2013 and this started happening. does anyone know why?

...why I got the error, not why I changed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this exact same issue... I tracked it down to one of the assemblies I referenced from a project in my solution, which referenced Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll v 10.0.0.0. As this was one of my own assemblies that I had cross-purposed as a debugger visualizer for VS2010, I went back and removed all that code and the reference, and voila VS2013 visualizers work again.

Use Process Explorer .dll view and you will see what is loaded and when into devenv.exe, this may help you see which assembly is the culprit. Also, ILSpy or equivalent would show you references a .dll makes.

Comment: so i would have to also remove all code for my runtime debugger?

Comment: Only anything that references Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll probably